# Resizing a component added to the canvas by dragging along the edge

Tags: flex3, resize

I am developing an application where I need  to place rectangular slabs of different shapes to create the shape of a Bench Top. I am placing the rectangular slabs of different shapes(I am using a the Canvas container as the slab) in a repeater and dragging them on the main canvas. One functionality that needs to be implemented is the ability to resize these slabs once the are dragged from the repeater into the drawing canvas by dragging along their edges like we resize the windows that we normally see. Is there any way this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an component developed for the purpose

http://www.rogue-development.com/objectHandles.html

I am going to check it out.

Please inform if anyone has any other solutions.